# Support multiple schemas in Proto3

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

I am creating a proto3 schema that allow multiple/arbitrary data in incoming jsonObject. I would like to convert the incoming json object in one shot.

for example

```
{"key1":"value",
 "key2": {  //schema A}
 }
```

I also want to support for schema B for key2 in different request.

```
{"key1":"value",
 "key2": {  //schema B}
 }
```

I tried couple of different approach such as `oneof` but for `oneof` it needs different key names, since I am using the same `key2`, it does not work for me in this case.

and here is the schema.

```
message IncomingRequest {
string key1 = 1;
//google.protobuf.Any key2 = 2;  --> not working
    oneof message{
        A payload = 2; 
        B payload = 3; --> duplicate key
    } 
}
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

### Message types for each request

If you know, based on the request (e.g. HTTP URL called), if it should be schema A or B, I recommend to create separate message types for each request. This might result in more proto types you have to define, but will be simple to use in the actual code you have to write to consume the payloads.

### Struct type

If you really want/have to reuse the same message type you can use the [Struct proto type](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) to encode/decode any JSON structure.

```
message IncomingRequest {
    string key1 = 1;
    google.protobuf.Struct key2 = 2;
}
```

Although from the proto type definition it doesn't look like it does what you want, Protobuf decoders/encoders will handle this type in a special way to give you the behavior wanted.

The issue with this option is that what you gain in flexibility in the proto, you lose in expressiveness in the generated code, as you have to do a lot edge-case checking if a specific value/type is set.